# How to reload Interstitial Google Ads (New Version) in Kotlin Android

Tags: android, kotlin, admob, interstitial

I have added Interstitial Google Ads in my Kotlin project. It is loading only once and when I am trying to re-show it, it's not showing.

```
// Defined variable on top
private var mInterstitialAd: InterstitialAd? = null

    MobileAds.initialize(requireContext()) {}
    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    adView.loadAd(adRequest)


        InterstitialAd.load(requireContext(),"---Interstitial Unit id---", adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
            override fun onAdFailedToLoad(adError: LoadAdError) {
                Log.d("LoadAdTAG", adError?.message)
                mInterstitialAd = null
            }

            override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAd: InterstitialAd) {
                Log.d("LoadAdTAG", "Ad was loaded.")
                mInterstitialAd = interstitialAd
            }
        })

        mInterstitialAd?.fullScreenContentCallback = object: FullScreenContentCallback() {
            override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                Log.d("LoadAdTAG", "Ad was dismissed.")
            }

            override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError?) {
                Log.d("LoadAdTAG", "Ad failed to show.")
            }

            override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                Log.d("LoadAdTAG", "Ad showed fullscreen content.")
//                mInterstitialAd = null
            }
        }
```

And then I am showing it on some condition after some time. The first time it is showing as below

```
mInterstitialAd?.show(requireActivity())
```

But next time when trying to show, this line gets called but Ad is not showing.

Could you please help me out with how to show the ad again?

I have followed below Google Docs (new version): https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add this code:-

```
fun loadAds() {
    val adRequest = AdRequest.Builder().build()
    InterstitialAd.load(requireActivity(), interstitial_id, adRequest, object : InterstitialAdLoadCallback() {
        override fun onAdLoaded(interstitialAds: InterstitialAd) {
            mInterstitialAd = interstitialAds

            mInterstitialAd!!.fullScreenContentCallback = object : FullScreenContentCallback() {
                override fun onAdDismissedFullScreenContent() {
                    loadAds()
                }

                override fun onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent(adError: AdError) {}
                override fun onAdShowedFullScreenContent() {
                    mInterstitialAd = null
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onAdFailedToLoad(loadAdError: LoadAdError) {
            mInterstitialAd = null
        }
    })
}
```

add this code for show ads:-

```
if (mInterstitialAd != null) {
        mInterstitialAd!!.show(requireActivity())
    }
```